# Как сделать такой эффект при ховере?

Tags: html, jquery, css, css3, html5

Справа нормальный вид, слева при ховере

[image: Элемент при ховере]

Хотя бы натолкните на мысль как это реализовать

Comment: а ты покажи свои попытки

Comment: Я не пытался, идеи даже нет

Comment: а в html нельзя картинку сделать прозрачной но при ховере видимой

Comment: здесь в роли картинки выступает синие полосы

Comment: Это можно, но будет убого смотреться, мне нужно линии отрисовывать по очереди и быстро

Comment: @SeeSharp почему это нельзя? Все можно.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Пример

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  padding: 1rem;
}

.title {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1;
  padding: 0 1rem;
}

.title__line {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  background: #95A7FF;
  transition: width .3s linear;
  transition-delay: .3s;
}

.title__line:nth-of-type(2) {
  top: 15px;
  left: 10%;
  transition-delay: .4s;
}

.title__line:nth-of-type(3) {
  top: 20px;
  left: 10%;
  transition-delay: .5s;
}

.title__line:nth-of-type(4) {
  top: 25px;
  left: 15%;
  transition-delay: .6s;
}

.title__line:nth-of-type(5) {
  top: 30px;
  left: 15%;
  transition-delay: .7s;
}

.title__line:nth-of-type(6) {
  top: 35px;
  left: 20%;
  transition-delay: .8s;
}

.title__line:nth-of-type(7) {
  top: 40px;
  left: 25%;
  transition-delay: .9s;
}

.title:hover .title__line:nth-of-type(1),
.title:hover .title__line:nth-of-type(3),
.title:hover .title__line:nth-of-type(6) {
  width: 80%;
}

.title:hover .title__line:nth-of-type(2) {
  width: 70%;
}

.title:hover .title__line:nth-of-type(4) {
  width: 90%;
}

.title:hover .title__line:nth-of-type(5),
.title:hover .title__line:nth-of-type(7) {
  width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="title">
  <span class="title__line"></span>
  <span class="title__line"></span>
  <span class="title__line"></span>
  <span class="title__line"></span>
  <span class="title__line"></span>
  <span class="title__line"></span>
  <span class="title__line"></span> Title text
</h1>
```

Comment: Благодарочка за пример